# Isometric world scrolling Java

Tags: java, graphics, scroll, isometric

So I created an isometric world and I made that it scrolls the world when you use the W A S D keys. Now what I did is actually move all the world according to the player's movement and not the player. Is this a good way of doing it? I have some weird graphics glitches that at the top left of the world (ONLY TOP LEFT) the tiles start glitching and flashing... I am using Graphics2D..

Here is how I am doing it:
The shifter it self:

```
public void checkForShift(Player p, World world, GameWindow win) {
    //X MOVING

    if (p.getEnty().getX()>win.getWidth()/2) {
        if (p.getEnty().getX()<world.getWidth()-win.getWidth()/2) {
            temp = (p.getEnty().getX()-win.getWidth()/2);
            world.subSWidth(temp);
            world.subWidth(temp);
            world.updateShift(1, temp);
        }
    }
    if (p.getEnty().getX()<win.getWidth()/2) {
        if (p.getEnty().getX()>world.getSwidth()+win.getWidth()/2) {
            temp = (p.getEnty().getX()-(world.getSwidth()+win.getWidth()/2));
            world.addSWidth(temp);
            world.addWidth(temp);
            world.updateShift(2, temp);
        }
    }
    //Y MOVING
    if (p.getEnty().getY()>win.getHeight()/2) {
        if (p.getEnty().getY()<world.getHeight()-win.getHeight()/2) {
            temp = (p.getEnty().getY()-win.getHeight()/2);
            world.subSHeight(temp);
            world.subHeight(temp);
            world.updateShift(3, temp);
        }
    }
    if (p.getEnty().getY()<win.getHeight()/2) {
        if (p.getEnty().getY()>world.getSheight()+win.getHeight()/2) {
            temp = (p.getEnty().getY()-(world.getSheight()+win.getHeight()/2));
            world.addSHeight(temp);
            world.addHeight(temp);
            world.updateShift(4, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

world:

```
public void updateShift(int operation, int amount) {
    for(Entity e:ListManager.entityList) {
        e.updateShift(operation, amount);
    }
    for (Chunk c : this.getChunkList()) {
        for (Tile t : c.getTileList()) {
            t.updateShift(operation, amount);
        }
    }
}
```

entity:

```
public void updateShift(int operation, int amount) {
    if (operation == 1) {
        SubX(amount);
    } else if (operation == 2) {
        AddX(amount);
    } else if (operation == 3) {
        SubY(amount);
    } else {
        AddY(amount);
    }

}
```

tiles:

```
public void updateShift(int operation, int amount) {
    if (operation == 1) {
        SubX(amount);
    } else if (operation == 2) {
        AddX(amount);
    } else if (operation == 3) {
        SubY(amount);
    } else {
        AddY(amount);
    }
}
```

So i have 2 questions, Is this a good and performance efficient way of doing this? and how do I fix the weird glitches? Here is a video:

http://youtu.be/YUn5xCeBInM

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my response would be a bit off, but you may be interested in [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) and its  [IsometricMap](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/source/browse/) sample.

Comment: Yeah its really off, its not gonna help me.. Thanks anyways

Comment: I tried some stuff out, did't help anyone know how to fix it?